# Window on condition

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable of numbers `[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3]` and want to window it by groups of same remainder of the division by two. So, resulting observable of observables will be `[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4], [1, 3]]`. How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does the source observable emit the numbers one by one are in an array?

Comment: @daflodedeing one by one. Observable<number>.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm nothing, struggle to find any useful function in rxjs. In theory solution algo is "window observable any time next element have different reminder of div by two", but how it can be achieved in reality?

Comment: Ok, and the numbers emitted are not only the numbers above? So the list of lists of remainders is dynamic? Should the type of the resulting Observable be `Observable<Observable<number>>`?

Comment: @daflodedeing yes, emitted numbers are not only as in example, so remainders. And resulting Observable type should be `Observable<Observable<number>>`.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet can produce the results you want, although I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this.

The `reduce` will add numbers to the last subarray, until one of them does not have the same result with the others when divided by two.

The `map` converts the array of subarrays to array of observables

```
from([1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 3])
  .pipe(
    reduce((result, num) => {
      const lastArray = result[result.length - 1];
      if (lastArray.length > 0 && lastArray[0] % 2 == num % 2) {
        lastArray.push(num);
        result[result.length - 1] = lastArray;
      } else {
        result.push([num]);
      }
      return result;
    }, [[]]),
    map((array: any[]) => array.map((subarray) => from(subarray)))
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    res.forEach((obs, i) =>
      obs.subscribe((data) => console.log(data, 'observable ' + i))
    );
  });
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ttx8bm?file=index.ts)